# Removing nested for loops

Tags: rust

I am currently working on a project, in which I am referencing a grid quite often. This grid uses both X and Y axis. When I want to iterate through the grid I use two nested for loops, one for each axis.

```
for x in range 0..10
{
    for y in range 0..20
    {

    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was any way to make this more neat / easier to read by using only one line of code. To look more like...

```
for x in range 0..10 && y in range 0..20
{

}
```

This would generally help the readability. This obviously assumes there would be no code in just the x loop.

Comment: This use case is supported by the `iproduct` macro in the fantastic [itertools crate](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/macro.iproduct.html). You'd write something like `for (x, y) in iproduct!(0..10, 0..20) { ... `

Comment: @SirDarius proposition is possibly the best, but if you want to do it yourself without importing a crate you could do `for (i, j) in (0..5).flat_map(|i| (0..5).map(move |j| (i, j))) { ...` yeah it look messy, but does the job [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0887fc7082f0b00297b8dbe7e2c91231)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, `.flat_map()` is the way to go to avoid writting nested expressions in a classical way, and without adding external deps to your project.

```
fn main() {
    for (i, j) in (0..10).flat_map(|i| (0..20).map(move |j| (i, j))) {
        // do job here
    }
}
```